# Count of multiple customer ID shown in a Microsoft Access crosstab query

Tags: ms-access, crosstab

I am trying to build a crosstab query in Microsoft Access that does the following

**STARTING DATA**

```
Segment  |   Customer ID

10       |    5

12       |    5

11       |    5

11       |    7

10       |    10

12       |    10
```

**OUTPUT**

```
      10  |  11  |   12

10     2  |  1   |  2

11     1  |  2   |  1

12     2  |  1   |  2
```

Basically I am trying to show a count by segment any time the customerID is the same for two separate segments.  For example, customerID 5 is shared across segments 10 & 12 and Customer ID 10 is shared across segments 10 & 12 so on the table at the intersection of 10 & 12 it shows 2 (the count of all customers who are in both segments 10 & 12).

Any help you have would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This requires a self join on the CustomerID column.  The question didn't explicitly name the source, so I call it `CS`.  A self join is not different than other joins, only that aliases are necessary so that it's possible to separately refer to the different instances of the same source.  Here the aliases are `CS1` and `CS2`.

```
TRANSFORM Count(CS1.CustomerID) AS CountOfCustomerID
SELECT CS1.Segment
FROM CS AS CS1 INNER JOIN CS AS CS2 ON CS1.CustomerID = CS2.CustomerID
GROUP BY CS1.Segment
ORDER BY CS1.Segment, CS2.Segment
PIVOT CS2.Segment;
```

Although in this case it is possible to define all necessary joins in the single select statement as part of the CrossTab query, it is often enlightening to view the Select result separately without the transform.  In other words, I suggesting inspecting

```
SELECT CS1.Segment AS Segment1, CS2.Segment AS Segment2, CS1.CustomerID AS CustomerID
FROM CS AS CS1 INNER JOIN CS AS CS2 ON CS1.CustomerID = CS2.CustomerID
ORDER BY CS1.Segment, CS2.Segment, CS1.CustomerID;
```

Studying the results of that query--and being aware of self joins--would hopefully help in crafting similar queries in the future.